# Show only the in stock product attribute in layered navigation - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to modify magento core functionality which is show only the in stock product attribute in layered navigation when allow out of stock products in  front end.

Comment: have you checked http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/13546/2206?

Comment: this? http://colin.mollenhour.com/2009/07/14/hiding-out-of-stock-items-in-layered-navigation/

Comment: Yes I Know this option  @DushyantJoshi . But I want to show out of stock products in category listing and no need to show in filtered results

Comment: Yes I tried. But it did not work @DushyantJoshi

Comment: I think the following is what you want https://github.com/tzyganu/stock-filter

Comment: No this is not what i want.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Please rephrase the question ....

Answer (score 0):

Is the situation

a) you have set `allow out of stock products in front end` to YES in the backend config under catalog. As a result 2 things happen: 1. out of stock products are still reachable (directly) by the old url & 2. the options of these out of stock products still seem to exist in the layered navigation as options to choose (but there are not products)

b) child products with a related atrtibute (often SIZE or COLOR or VARIANT) are shown in the layered navigation fitlers, nut when you click the filter it shows all the products with the child product attribute: both in and out of stock. A user would expect to see only the in stock products after clicking their size